# Can Master Chief be a leftie?

Tags: halo-2

In some FPS engines (notably Quake and some Cube derivatives) you can change the handedness of the player (so that the HUD gun is on the left). Since I am a left-handed shooter, I prefer this alignment, but I cannot seem to find any options in Halo 2 to switch to left-handed.

Is this possible in the Halo engine? (Specifically Halo 2 for Windows Vista).

Comment: I believe they got rid of the genetically inferior lefties in the future. :)

Comment: Oh no! D: why can't we live in peace!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the answer is no, a quick search of Google pulls up nothing helpful.  [This link](http://books.google.com/books?id=VR1s0GW9iIMC&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=halo%202%20left%20handed%20mod&source=bl&ots=TK9_8dJvSi&sig=qZkWx9NEtLWD2G91oIbegQSx3Xo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aTffT-T9HISm8ASj79HgCg&ved=0CFYQ6AEwAQ) on modding states that there is no left handed animation for some weapons.